# Trying to get leaderboard 728x90 with 4 little ads, but getting 2-Line ads instead

Tags: adsense

Trying to get leaderboard 728x90 with 4 little ads, but getting 2-Line ads instead... HELP!

am using the following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    google_ad_client = "<?= $googleSettingObj->getString("value") ?>";
                    google_ad_width = 728;
                    google_ad_height = 90;
                    google_ad_format = "728x90_as";
                    google_ad_type = "text_image";
                    google_ad_channel = "<?= $googleSettingObj_Channel->getString("value") ?>";
                    google_color_border = "336699";
                    google_color_bg = "FFFFFF";
                    google_color_link   = "0000FF";
                    google_color_url    = "008000";
                    google_color_text   = "000000";
                </script>
                <script type="text/javascript"
                        src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
                </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

AdSense **does not provide the ability to change the format of the 728x90 unit** for normal accounts. You can set your unit to display text, image, or both, but besides the font, color, and corner style options that are made clearly available, you can't change anything about the text unit. AdSense will fill the unit with one, two, three, or four ads, depending on the results of its ad auction algorithm. It can change from pageload to pageload and user to user also.